# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error when splitting strings

Tags: java

```
String[] syntax = command.split(" ");

if(syntax[1] == "cd"){

    cd cd = new cd();
    cd.getCD();
```

Whenever I run this, I get an error thats confusing. I am almost 100% sure this has to do with strings or escaping. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Examples on the values of command please?

Comment: You should take a look at [how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Also `I get an error thats confusing` is not helpful way to describe your error.

Comment: Where to start. Classes should start with a capital (`CD`, not `cd`). Arrays are zero-indexed. Compare strings (and other objects) with `.equals`, not `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible issues:

When comparing Strings, use .equals(), not ==.

The first element of an array is always 0, not 1.

Comment: I guess it is always one possible issue that is related to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions that is the used index does not exist. comparing strings with either == or equals() is not the main issue as long as the string to be compared doesn't exit.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your `if-statement`. Also use `.equals()` not `==` for strings.
Can you show of the rest of the code? I made a small working program with your code.

In Java `==` is the reference of the object, but `equals()` checks if it's the identical string (character by character is identical).

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` might have occurred since you chose `index 1` instead of `0`. Since indexes start at `0` in Java this might be your problem.

Working example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command = "cd temp";
    String[] syntax = command.split(" ");

    if(syntax[0].equals("cd")){
        CD cd = new CD();
        cd.getCD();
        System.out.println(cd.getCD());
    }
}
static class CD {
    private String title;

    public CD() {
        title = "unnamed";
    }

    public String getCD() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that it is not problem then why you are posting this as answer instead of comment?

Comment: @Pshemo I can't put code in comment. Also the issue might be index etc. so I'm going to make a working example here!

Comment: First part of your answer: `You haven't closed your if-statement. Also use .equals() not == for strings. Can you show of the rest of the code?` is good comment, but it doesn't answer the question why OP is getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also showing working example is not the same as explaining what changes you made and why ware they necessary.